# Get date range of week from a given date range

Tags: python

I've been trying to break a given date range into date range each week, but couldn't find any effective way to do it.

Let's say I have input: 05/05/2020 (Tues) - 04/06/2020, and the out put would be like

('05/05/2020', '10/05/2020'),

('11/05/2020', '17/05/2020'),
....

Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should start a loop from the first date and run it till you find the first Sunday. When you hit the first Sunday, You get your first week. After that just keep adding 7 days to get the next week. While adding 7 days check if next Sunday date is falling within the provided range. if it is going outside the range, set the last date of the provided range as the ending date of last week instead of Sunday.